# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool' - firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

i just updated my Firebase pods to the newest version and instantly im getting some errors (not a shock :) ) .

My app will take incoming dynamic links and redirect them, but im getting error at `if let linkHandled`

The error says `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if let incomingUrl = userActivity.webpageURL {
        if let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingUrl, completion: { (dynamicLink, _) in
            if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink, let _ = dynamicLink.url {
                self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink: dynamicLink)
            }
        }) {
            return linkHandled
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I didnt have this error before i updated, anyone got an idea of what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use optional binding to find out whether an optional contains a value, and if so, to make that value available as a temporary variable. In your case, you don't have to use optional binding on a non-optional bool:

```
let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingUrl, completion: { (dynamicLink, _) in
    if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink, let _ = dynamicLink.url {
        self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink: dynamicLink)
    }
})

if linkHandled {
    return linkHandled
}
```

Or more succinctly, as recommended by **@LeoDabus** in the comments, you could use Swift's trailing closure syntax when initializing `linkHandled`:

```
let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingUrl) { (dynamicLink, _) in
    if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink, let _ = dynamicLink.url {
        self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink: dynamicLink)
    }
}
```

Your whole function would look like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if let incomingUrl = userActivity.webpageURL {

        let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingUrl, completion: { (dynamicLink, _) in
            if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink, let _ = dynamicLink.url {
                self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink: dynamicLink)
            }
        })

        if linkHandled {
            return linkHandled
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: You can always use Swift's trailing closure syntax after the method and omit the last parameter (completion). `handleUniversalLink(incomingUrl) { ... }`

Comment: I mentioned your recommendation in the updated answer.